# How to write the file yml many-to-many table with 3 PrimaryKey

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, yaml, doctrine-1.2

if our situation is the standard view where you have two tables and a ternary, and easily manageable by following the [following documentation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/pl/yaml-schema-files#relationships%3amany-to-many)

But if we have three instead of two tables and then the ternary consists of 3 PrimaryKey, as I write my yml files?

**Example to situation:**

Take the case that I have a user who participates in a course.
So I have a `users` table, `courses` table and a `users_has_courses` (useri_id, course_id).
This is the standard case many-to-many.
But I also have a table `invoices` and therefore a table `users_courses_invoices` where there are three  primaykey (user_id, course_id, invoice_id).

Comment: how are the tables linked ? ie Users has many Groups and Groups has many users ....

Comment: @ManseUK: i add example to situation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation you have the `User` and the `Course` model and they are linked with a many to many relation which has the pair `(user_id, course_id)` as key. I would call this model subscription, and give to that its own identifier, and then I will link this model with the `Invoice` model, so your final scheme (minimal version) could be:

```
User:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true

Course:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true

Subscription:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    user_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
    course_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
  relations:
    User:
      foreignAlias: Subscriptions
    Course:
      foreignAlias: Subscriptions

Invoice:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer
      primary: true
    subscription_id:
      type: integer
      notnull: true
  relations:
    Subscription:
      foreignAlias: Subscription
      foreignType: One
```

In this way you have a normalized database and you can access invoices both from users and from courses with this code:

```
$user->Subscriptions->getFirst()->Invoice
$course->Subscriptions->getFirst()->Invoice
```

If you want all invoices for a given users you can do a query in this way

```
InvoiceTable::getInstance()->createQuery('i')
    ->select('i.*')
    ->leftJoin('i.Subscription s')->leftJoin('s.User u')
    ->where('u.id = ?', $user_id);
```

The same apply if you want all the invoices for a given course.

Comment: Ok! Your speech does not bat an eyelid! But at present I have the table `Subscription` with `user_id` and `course_id` as PrimaryKey. I do not have the `id` field! :S

Comment: @JellyBelly you can always write a migration to add it (which IMHO is the best solution)... Alternatively I can't remember if you can indicate a pair as a foreign key in Doctrine as in `local: [user_id, course_id] foreign: [user_id, course_id]` for the `Subscription` relation in the `Invoice` model. Or you can add a couple of custom methods in the `Invoice` and `Subscription` models which do the right query to fetch related records.

Comment: reason I believe that I go back on my feet. I make a alter table on table to add the id, otherwise I do not know how to get out. Thanks